# How to define the index signature in TypeScript, but the value does not use union types?

Tags: typescript

I know we can define index signature like this:

```js
interface Foo {
  [index: string]: number | string
}
```

But I want the type of value can only be `number` or `string`,
not `number | string`,
because I need to use it as a constraint like this:

```js
type Bar<T extends Foo> = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I finally came up with another *solution* (more like a workaround) that actually includes an extension of the types using [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). The sad part here is that mixing `string` and `number` still does not work properly. However you can declare the type as `string` or whatever you want and just extend it with `any`.

```
interface Foo {
  [index: string]: string;
}

type Bar<T extends Foo> = { [P in keyof Foo]: Foo[keyof Foo] | T[keyof T] };

const bar: Bar<{ [index: string]: any }> = {
  someProperty: "1",
  anotherProperty: 2,
};
```

---

I know you asked for a [`Type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) [`Generic`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that extends `Foo`. I came up with a solution without that. So if you want to make that compromise here you go:

```
interface Foo {
  [index: string]: number;
}

type Bar<T> = { [index: string]: Foo[keyof Foo] | T[keyof T] };

const bar: Bar<{ someProperty: string }> = {
  someProperty: "1",
  anotherProperty: 2,
};
```

Basically what I did was taking your `Foo` interface and only allowed property value types of

- `Foo[keyof Foo]` -> In the example above [`number`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#number) and
- `T[keyof T]` -> In the example above [`string`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#string) (because of `{ someProperty: string }`)

using [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html).

In conclusion now the property value types of the `bar`-object can only be `string` or `number` (respectively `number | T[keyof T]` to be exact) without hard-coding the types as `string | number` in `Foo`.

---

Another example with [`boolean`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#boolean):

```
interface Foo {
  [index: string]: number;
}

type Bar<T> = { [index: string]: Foo[keyof Foo] | T[keyof T] };

const bar: Bar<{ someProperty: boolean }> = {
  someProperty: "1", // error!
  // ~~~~~~~~~> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | boolean'. ts(2322)
  anotherProperty: 2,
};
```

---

Note that it is not possible (yet) to set a type for the index signature dynamically like so:

```
interface Foo {
  [index: string]: number;
}

type Bar<T> = { [index: keyof Foo]: ... };
```

Check out this issue/suggestion:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1778

So it's kinda hard to mix `string` key type and `number` key type.

```
interface Foo {
  [index: number]: number;
}

type Bar<T> = { [index: number]: Foo[keyof Foo] | T[keyof T] };

const bar: Bar<{ 0: string }> = {
  0: "1", // error!
//~> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
  anotherProperty: 2,
};
```